# PHP Query Call Issue

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have two tables in my database:

1) blog_table
2) content

In `blog_table` I have values called `postID` that may or may not match up to values called `id` in the table `content`.  I am wanting to know how I can write a while loop or foreach loop that will cycle through `content` table and perform one action if the `id` equals the value of `postID` in the `blog_table` and perform a different action if it doesn't.

Right now I can only get `id` = `postID`

```
$blog_table = $_REQUEST['blog_table'];  
$getblogtable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE type = '5' AND blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' ORDER BY `order` ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogtable)) 
{
$getblogposts1 = mysql_query("SELECT postID FROM `$blog_table`");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogposts1)) 
{
 if( $row1['postID'] == $row['id']) {
      echo "do something<br>";
 }else{
     echo "do something else<br>";
 }
} echo "<p></p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit based on OP's comments and revised question]

```
$getblogposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE type = '5' AND blogID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogposts))
{
    $matches = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $blog_table WHERE postID = $row['id']");
    if (mysql_num_rows($matches) > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Regarding a different design, I can't say for sure that it's necessary, but I don't like running a loop of queries like this.  I think one query should be enough to get everything you need in this case.  Maybe if you describe your application, we could find a better query or more appropriate design.

Comment: Okay, so I keep having the same problem.  I have changed the code in my post and let me explain: let's say I have 4 values in the table `content` that have the same type and blogID and I have 3 values in the table `blog_table`...then the inside loop gets done 4 times, which will give me  3 results per iteration.  I just want 1 result per iteration.  So in all, when this code executes I should just get 4 results (1 results per iteration which this code should iterate 4 times if I have 4 items in my table `content`)

Comment: First, let me know if this describes what you're trying to do: 1. get the rows in `content` that are associated with a certain `blogID` 2. iterate through those rows looking for ones that are associated with a certain `postID`

Comment: 1. you are correct. 2. I am wanting to iterate through those to see if the `id`'s match postID in another table, but if they don't match I want something else to happen (which is where `else` comes in).

Comment: I edited to I think reflect what you're looking for.  What the new code does is check to see if `content.id` appears at least once in the `$blog_table.postID` column.

Comment: Let me try that. I'm pretty alright with database design, but this one had me stumped for some reason.

Comment: I did have everything in one table at first, but I couldn't figure out how to make this code work for the blog so I made a separate table just for the blog.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing an easier to see solution for you to your problem.

I suggest using inner joins which will solve the issue at hand.

For example, Something like:

SELECT * FROM content AS C INNER JOIN $blog_table AS B on B.postID = C.id

Here is a great introduction to joins (inner, left, right, full):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$blog_table = $_REQUEST['blog_table'];  
$getblogtable = mysql_query("SELECT postID FROM `$blog_table`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogtable)) 
{
  $postID = $row['postID'];
  $getblogposts1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE id = '$postID' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
  while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getblogposts1)) 
  {
     // if( $row1[id] == $postId )
     //     do something
     // else
     //     do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: do u really think your code will ever come to the else section? you are only getting contents where id = postID, have  loot at your answer

Comment: It's more of an example to show how he can do one thing or do something else with the results.

The example isn't limited to just his post.

Comment: Okay, so I keep having the same problem.  I have changed the code in my post and let me explain: let's say I have 4 values in the table `content` that have the same type and blogID and I have 3 values in the table `blog_table`...then the inside loop gets done 4 times, which will give me  3 results per iteration.  I just want 1 result per iteration.  So in all, when this code executes I should just get 4 results (1 results per iteration which this code should iterate 4 times if I have 4 items in my table `content`)

Comment: Could I make a suggestion on changing the query at all?

Something like:

SELECT * FROM content AS C INNER JOIN $blog_table AS B on B.postID = C.id

Comment: yes, i like it, i will play with that and see what I can make of it.  I've never used joining, but I forgot that I could do that!  So does that basically eliminate the need for the inner while loop?  I'm new to that type of query.